# phpMyAdmin: no row selected when deleting multiple rows

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin 4.4.14. When I try to delete multiple rows from a table, I get

> "No rows selected"

but the rows are deleted.

[image]

Comment: Does it work when deleting a single row?, maybe it's because you use 3 statements try 'id' IN (8,9,10) instead

Comment: You should really consider upgrading phpmyadmin to the latest version

Comment: @Jojo01 This person is already running the latest stable version.

Answer (score 2):

This has been reported and fixed for the upcoming 4.4.15 version:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11431